# Where is the shown sleeping area at Schiphol airport?

Tags: airports, identify-this, ams

I'm soon flying to Schiphol arriving in the late evening, and wish to sleep airside before continuing my journey by train in the early morning.

Came across the below image which is reportedly in the D pier airside. Could anyone please clarify:

1. Is the shown location in the Schengen or non-Schengen sector (the D pier is divided)?
2. Are there other similar airside spots with furniture to properly lie down on?

[image: 1]

Comment: Google Street View has photos inside the terminals, did you try that?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, didn't help

Comment: https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/amsterdam-airport-guide.htm is another famous source for airport sleepers, did you check there?

Comment: @gmauch Yes, in fact that's where I found the photo (another page about Schiphol)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, based on the trees and similarity to other photos, that picture is from the [Airport Park](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/at-schiphol/relax-and-enjoy/airport-park) area at Schiphol.

Here's [a 2011 photo](http://chaney.kwak.in/amsterdam-schiphol/) that shows the beanbag chairs, trees, and semi-reclined chairs from a different angle.

However:

> Important: Due to the measures to prevent the spread of the corona virus the Airport Park is closed temporarily

Comment: Yeah, it's in the Airport Park, which is at the "base" of the D pier (where it meets the main terminal building). It's on the upper (Schengen) floor of the D-pier (the lower floor of D is non-Schengen and there's no way to access the Airport Park from there without passing immigration).

Comment: @TooTea: but that is not a problem. The journey will continue with train, so OP should pass immigration.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Sure, I just mentioned it for completeness for the benefit of potential future readers.

Comment: The link mentions that _Opening hours: 9:00 - 17:00_. So not appropriate for a night sleep.